# Adjust the interval for setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create function that increments numbers, so it looks like a digital clock kind of thing. The function takes two timestamps as param and increments between those. But since hh(hours) has a smaller range than mm(minutes), the hours always finishes first. I want the two to finish at the same time.

Here is my code.

```
    var start =  $('.clock').attr('data-from').split(":"); //eg. 10:23
    var end = $('.clock').attr('data-to').split(":"); //eg 18:38

    var clock = function (start, end, el) {
        if($('.clock').length) {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                el.text(start);
                if (start >= end) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
                start++;
            }, 50);
        }

    };

    clock(start[0],end[0],$('.clock .h'));
    clock(start[1],end[1],$('.clock .m'));
```

So, how can I make the interval to finish both animations at the same time?

Comment: Do you have any plunker or jsbin that we can use?

Comment: So one animation should go from say 10 to 20 and another animation from 30 to 50 both in eg. 10 seconds?

Comment: You could just add an `interval` parameter to your `clock` function and pass in an interval instead of hardcoding it to `50`.

Comment: @RolandStarke exactly! jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qjqnwz2p/3/

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjqnwz2p/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer was not properly using a "time to animate" effectively and some values would post slower than others so I removed that one and simplified it down to this: fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/67wyzk2m/2/

**Markup**

```
<div class="container" data-from="01:00" data-to="18:50">
  <span class="h"></span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span class="m"></span>
</div>
```

**New code:**

```
var clockR = function(start, end, el, timerP) {
  var currentCount = start;
  el.text(currentCount);
  var timer = timerP || 1;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    el.text(currentCount);
    if (start >= end) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    currentCount++;
  }, timer);
};
var start = $('.container').attr('data-from').split(":");
var end = $('.container').attr('data-to').split(":");
var animateLength = 30000; // ms to count for
var s0 = end[0] - start[0];
var s1 = end[1] - start[1];
var t0 = Math.abs(Math.trunc(animateLength / s0));
var t1 = Math.abs(Math.trunc(animateLength / s1));

clockR(start[0], end[0], $('.container .h'), t0);
clockR(start[1], end[1], $('.container .m'), t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a number they can both (hours and minutes) divide.

So let's say you want to go from 10:20 to 12:30, the hour difference is 2 and the minutes difference is 10. Multiply them, you get 20.

Let's say you want your all animation to happen within 100 millisecond.

Divide your 100 by 20, you get 5. So 5 will be your interval.
Divide 100 by 2 (the number of hours) = 50, the hours will have to be updated when the rest of the total of the intervals divided by 50 = 0, so `totalInterval % 50 === 0`.
Same for the minutes, 100/10 = 10, so when `totalInterval % 10 === 0`, increment your minutes.

I'm just giving you the guidelines here, your turn to code it ;)
If you could post your final solution here that'd be great.

Comment: Look ad that: https://jsfiddle.net/qjqnwz2p/6/
There is some more work to do for when the hours are going back to 00, same for the minutes, but you have the idea. Then you have a small problem with the if statement because you will get some super small numbers which won't be equal to 0 because of the dividing but should be.

Comment: @FlorianB Interesting  If I change the markup to `<div class="clock" data-from="01:20" data-to="22:30">` it seems to return/end at 12 . 30

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was talking about with the `(numberOfInterval * timeInterval) % intervalHour`, it is not exactly equal to 0 even though this is a super near number.

Comment: So I've put it back in 2 functions so it's easier to do calculations: https://jsfiddle.net/qjqnwz2p/7/